# Elastic Beanstalk: How do I import VPCId from another Cloudformation stack using .ebextensions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cloudformation

Is it possible to import the value for VPCId from other Cloudformation stacks using `Fn:ImportValue` in the `option_settings` in AWS Elastic Beanstalk?

Or do the values have to be hardcoded in at this point? Any pointers would be really appreciated!

This is a working `.ebextensions/config`, it deploys successfully:
For more context, the application is a simple node.js express server and I am deploying the stack using the `eb` cli

```
#.ebextensions/vpc.config
option_settings:
  aws:ec2:vpc:
    ELBScheme: internal
    VPCId: vpc-0620a64be983c807a
    Subnets: "subnet-0b2e7f79bdd53a4da,subnet-0f0f6471dc6130f0a,subnet-0ce654446fd42509a"
    ELBSubnets: "subnet-0b2e7f79bdd53a4da,subnet-0f0f6471dc6130f0a,subnet-0ce654446fd42509a"
    AssociatePublicIpAddress: true
```

This is the broken example with `VPCId` exported in another cloudformation stack with the value of `vpc-0620a64be983c807a`:

```
option_settings:
  aws:ec2:vpc:
    ELBScheme: internal
    VPCId: { "Fn::ImportValue" : "VPCId" }
    Subnets: "subnet-0b2e7f79bdd53a4da,subnet-0f0f6471dc6130f0a,subnet-0ce654446fd42509a"
    ELBSubnets: "subnet-0b2e7f79bdd53a4da,subnet-0f0f6471dc6130f0a,subnet-0ce654446fd42509a"
    AssociatePublicIpAddress: true
```

This is the error code, it seems like it isn't interpolating the vpcID after the elastic beanstalk bundle has been uploaded to AWS

```
2021-01-19 10:36:59    ERROR   "option_settings" in one of the configuration files failed validation. More details to follow.
2021-01-19 10:36:59    ERROR   Invalid option value: '["subnet-0ce654446fd425098","subnet-0b2e7f79bdd53a4df","subnet-0f0f6471dc6130f0c"]' (Namespace: 'aws:ec2:vpc', OptionName: 'Subnets'): Specify the VPC ID and make sure all subnets exist.
2021-01-19 10:37:00    ERROR   Invalid option value: 'subnet-0b2e7f79bdd53a4df,subnet-0f0f6471dc6130f0c,subnet-0ce654446fd425098' (Namespace: 'aws:ec2:vpc', OptionName: 'ELBSubnets'): Specify the VPC ID and make sure all subnets exist.
2021-01-19 10:37:00    ERROR   Failed to launch environment.
```

Update:
Backticks and Quotations were suggested, however it seems like it then treats the whole string literally in the VPC lookup

```
2021-01-19 11:31:05    ERROR   The VPC '`{ "fn::importvalue" :"vpcid" }`' does not exist.
```

Comment: These `option_settings` are from `.ebextentions` I guess. Not from `AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Environment`?

Comment: Can you check with [syntax](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions-otherkeys.html) (`TOPIC_ARN` example in the docs). Note all the quotation marks in this syntax: `VPCId: '\`{ "Fn::ImportValue" : "VPCId" }\`'`

Comment: They are from, `.ebextensions` have added a bit more context into the Question. Will try that syntax

Comment: Thank you very much for the help! Just an update on this, It seems like the backticks & the apostrophes caused the string to be used as the value of the VPCid rather than importing a value! (have updated the question with the error message!)

Comment: I tried to replicate the issue, and can confirm it does not work. I'm leaning towards that it is not possible, or at least not that straight forward. But if you were using CloudFormation to create your EB env, then there wouldn't be problem, as you wouldn't need to use ebextentions to setup your VPC.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time! I think you're right. Yes that would be great, I have a significant amount of EB environments to shift over to private VPCs. Have templated the .ebextension config file and injected in the IDs for now. Ultimately we will migrate to cloudforming them so that will solve it